# reshape data frame in pandas with pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
baz    qux    
one    A
one    B  
two    C   
three  A  
one    B   
one    C
```

I'm trying to reshape it to look like this:

```
one two three
A   C   A
B
B
C
```

I'm pretty confused about whether this is possible, and if so, how you would do it. I've tried using the `pivot_table` method as `pd.pivot_table(cols='baz', rows='qux')` but that threw a TypeError. I think I'm being an idiot and missing something really basic here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the most optimal way of doing it but it does the job:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = u'baz,qux\none,A\none,B\ntwo,C\nthree,A\none,B\none,C'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

new = pd.DataFrame()
for key, group in df.groupby('baz'):
    new = pd.concat([new, pd.DataFrame(group.reset_index().qux, columns=[key])],
                    axis=1)
print new.replace(np.nan, '')
```

Which gives back:

```
  one two three  
0   A   C     A
1   B
2   B
3   C
```

With pivot table you can get a matrix showing which `baz` corresponds to which `qux`:

```
>>> df['foo'] = 1 # Add aggregation column
>>> df.pivot_table('foo', cols='baz', rows=['qux'])
     one  three  two                 
A      1      1  NaN
B      1    NaN  NaN
C      1    NaN    1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what you asked for, but perhaps it suffices:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'baz':'one one two three one one'.split(),
                   'qux': list('ABCABC')})
grouped = df.groupby(['baz', 'qux'])
df2 = grouped.apply(pd.DataFrame.reset_index, drop=True)['qux'].unstack(level=0)

df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2 = df2.reindex(columns='one two three'.split())
df2 = df2.replace(np.nan, '')
print(df2)
```

yields

```
  one two three
0   A         A
1   B          
2   B          
3   C   C
```